# Set default subtitle language based on language code (eng, spa, etc.), not the stream specifier

Tags: ffmpeg, video, language, subtitles

I batch downloaded videos from a channel, but the subtitle languages available for each video are not consistent. Is there a way to set a default subtitle using the language code (e.g. eng, spa, fra, etc.) and NOT based on the stream specifier/number? And in **batch**?

---

Video1.mp4's English subtitle is at Stream#0:5 while Video2.mp4's English subtitle is at Stream#0:2.

Tried using `-disposition:s:1 default`, Video1.mp4's default subtitle became English (which is what I wanted), but now Video2.mp4's default became Spanish instead.

---

**Video1.mp4** metadata

```
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 626x360, 1231 kb/s, 26.20 fps, 26.17 tbr, 10k tbn, 52.39 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Stream #0:2(und): Video: mjpeg (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 640x368 [SAR 96:96 DAR 40:23], 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:3(und): Video: mjpeg (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 640x368 [SAR 96:96 DAR 40:23], 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:4(deu): Subtitle: mov_text (tx3g / 0x67337874), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
    Stream #0:5(eng): Subtitle: mov_text (tx3g / 0x67337874), 0 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
    Stream #0:6(spa): Subtitle: mov_text (tx3g / 0x67337874), 0 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
    Stream #0:7(spa): Subtitle: mov_text (tx3g / 0x67337874), 0 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
    Stream #0:8(fra): Subtitle: mov_text (tx3g / 0x67337874), 0 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
    Stream #0:9(ind): Subtitle: mov_text (tx3g / 0x67337874), 0 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
    Stream #0:10(ita): Subtitle: mov_text (tx3g / 0x67337874), 0 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
    Stream #0:11(por): Subtitle: mov_text (tx3g / 0x67337874), 0 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
    Stream #0:12(vie): Subtitle: mov_text (tx3g / 0x67337874), 0 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
    Stream #0:13(tur): Subtitle: mov_text (tx3g / 0x67337874), 0 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
    Stream #0:14(tha): Subtitle: mov_text (tx3g / 0x67337874), 0 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
    Stream #0:15(zho): Subtitle: mov_text (tx3g / 0x67337874), 0 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
    Stream #0:16(zho): Subtitle: mov_text (tx3g / 0x67337874), 0 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
    Stream #0:17(jpn): Subtitle: mov_text (tx3g / 0x67337874), 0 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
    Stream #0:18: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 640x368 [SAR 96:96 DAR 40:23], 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
```

**Video2.mp4** metadata

```
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720, 1309 kb/s, 29.90 fps, 29.90 tbr, 29899 tbn, 59.80 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 192 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: mov_text (tx3g / 0x67337874), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
    Stream #0:3(spa): Subtitle: mov_text (tx3g / 0x67337874), 0 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
    Stream #0:4(spa): Subtitle: mov_text (tx3g / 0x67337874), 0 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
    Stream #0:5(fra): Subtitle: mov_text (tx3g / 0x67337874), 0 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
    Stream #0:6(ind): Subtitle: mov_text (tx3g / 0x67337874), 0 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
    Stream #0:7(por): Subtitle: mov_text (tx3g / 0x67337874), 0 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
    Stream #0:8(vie): Subtitle: mov_text (tx3g / 0x67337874), 0 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
    Stream #0:9(eng): Subtitle: mov_text (tx3g / 0x67337874), 0 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
    Stream #0:10(zho): Subtitle: mov_text (tx3g / 0x67337874), 0 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
    Stream #0:11(kor): Subtitle: mov_text (tx3g / 0x67337874), 0 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
    Stream #0:12: Video: png, rgb24(pc), 1334x750, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
```

Hope you can help me. Thank you!

Comment: It looks like there is no such option. We may use shell script for finding the stream. Execute FFprobe for finding the stream specifier/number of the language: `ffprobe -loglevel error -select_streams s -show_entries stream=index:stream_tags=language -of csv=p=0 input.mkv`. Then execute FFmpeg with specifier/number. The answer is going to be different for Windows and Linux. With Python script it's going to be simpler.

Comment: @Rotem Thanks for replying! However, this would mean I have to check each video and then run them through ffmpeg one by one. I have hundreds of videos to fix so was hoping there was a way to automatically detect English subs, set it as default, and be able to do it in bulk.

Comment: A script may iterate multiple files. You are still not telling us if you are using Windows or Linux (or other). Note: Since you want to "batch process" multiple files, I am not going to post an answer, (maybe someone else is going to answer).

Comment: @Rotem I'm using Google Colab (which I know uses Linux?) and my files are on Drive.

Comment: Still new to this stuff so please bear with me.

Comment: I know (almost) nothing about Collab. I think this is now a different question, that is how to write batch scripts on Collab. You should probably ask a new question, with the appropriate tags (and before that make a bit of research...). Generally speaking, have you ever written batch scripts (whichever the script language)?

Comment: @PierU I've only written a very simple .bat file on Windows to merge video and audio files on ffmpeg, but never have and I don't know how for other scripting languages.

Comment: OK... Typically here you have to learn a bit of a scripting language (looping on files, set and use variables,...). I can't tell which one would be the most appropriate on Collab.

Comment: @PierU Thanks for the tip. I know Google Colab supports Python, so maybe I'll try that one.